# How to use an external script in React without addiing it to the html file

Tags: reactjs, global-variables, external-script

I am trying to figure out how to add external JS to a React app without adding it to the HTML file in a script tag.  The reason for this is that I have one component that needs access to an external script, but I can only access it as a global variable by adding `/*global <variabe name>*/` at the top of the component that needs it (as far as I know), which is not ideal.

I'm basically looking for an equivalent to

`const someScript = <script type="text/javascript" src="some url"></script>`

but in a way that actually works

This script is not needed when the app initially loads and could come in async.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install react script
Use npm install react-script-tag
And Add import which is
‘import ScriptTag from 'react-script-tag';’
And then you can use it